# VBA post method request body ("MSXML2.XMLHTTP"): Error Parsing JSON: ^ Expecting '{' or '['

Tags: json, vba, post, xmlhttprequest, postman

I'm trying to retrieve a JSON response object through the below query API. When I try to read the responseText in VBA I receive an empty result. However, the exact same request returns correct data from PostMan. Also, the correct data returns from sending the different request bodies. Whenever I try to execute `Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResponse)` and I'm getting the error message `Error Parsing JSON: ^ Expecting '{' or '['`. Can you please help?

This is VBA code

```
Dim strUrl As String
Dim reqBody As String
        
    'For search GOSS service API-Step1
    strUrl = "https://gossrepo.ins.dell.com/gossv3/api/reporting/service/getrefid"
        
    'create a method for calling HTTP services
    Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
        With hReq
            .Open "POST", strUrl, blnAsync, False
             reqBody = "{""methodType"":extract,""sourceApplication"":DSA,""searchParameter"":[{""conditionType"":term,""key"":global_bu_id,""value"":11},{""conditionType"":wildcard,""key"":customer_num,""value"":[530007546697]},{""conditionType"":range,""key"":order_date,""value"":[{""from"":2021-08-31,""to"":2021-09-09}]},{""conditionType"":sort,""key"":order_date_time,""value"":desc}],""pageSize"":40,""pageNum"":0}"
            .SetRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
            .Send reqBody
            While hReq.ReadyState <> 4
                DoEvents
            Wend
            'wrap the response in a JSON root tag "data" to count returned objects
            strResponse = hReq.ResponseText
            Debug.Print strResponse
        
        End With
    
    
    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResponse)
```

Updated the fixed with the different post body:

```
Dim strUrl As String
    Dim reqBody As String
        
    'For search GOSS service API-Step1
    strUrl = "https://gossrepo.us.dell.com/gossv3/api/reporting/service/getdata"
        
    'create a method for calling HTTP services
    Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
        With hReq
            .Open "POST", strUrl, blnAsync, False
             reqBody = "{""methodType"":""details"",""sourceApplication"":""DSA"",""pageNum"":0,""pageSize"":300,""searchParameter"":[{""conditionType"":""term"",""key"":""global_bu_id"",""value"":""11""},{""conditionType"":""wildcard"",""key"":""customer_num"",""value"":[""" & ws & """]},{""conditionType"":""range"",""key"":""order_date"",""value"":[{""from"":""" & ws11 & """,""to"":""" & ws12 & """}]},{""conditionType"":""sort"",""key"":""order_date_time"",""value"":""desc""}]}"
            .SetRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
            .Send reqBody
            While hReq.ReadyState <> 4
                DoEvents
            Wend
            'wrap the response in a JSON root tag "data" to count returned objects
            strResponse = hReq.ResponseText
            
            
        End With
    
    
    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResponse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your request is wrong and you don't get the expected response because of it... Look at the status that's returned (`hReq.status` and `hReq.statusText`), I bet it's `400 Bad Request` or `500 Internal Error` and not `200 Ok`. (You could also use an inspecting proxy like Fiddler to look at what exactly you send and receive here.)

I can already see your *request* body is invalid JSON as it has unquoted strings in it... It's not the exact same as you showed in Postman! That's like the issue (or one of the issues). You have e.g. `"methodType": extract`, but it has to be `"methodType": "extract"` (in VBA `""methodType"": ""extract""`) - you did it correctly in Postman but wrong in your code.

Comment: I'm getting the `12019` characters whenever I print the `hReq.status`. @CherryDT

Comment: Tried to make correction on the request body `"{""methodType"":""extract"",""sourceApplication"":""DSA"",""searchParameter"":[{""conditionType"":""term"",""key"":""global_bu_id"",""value"":""11""},{""conditionType"":""wildcard"",""key"":""customer_num"",""value"":[""530007546697""]},{""conditionType"":""range"",""key"":order_date,""value"":[{""from"":""2021-08-31"",""to"":""2021-09-09""}]},{""conditionType"":""sort"",""key"":""order_date_time"",""value"":""desc""}],""pageSize"":""40"",""pageNum"":""0""}"` However, still not getting any response. Also, there is no any error message.  @CherryDT

Comment: `order_date` is still not quoted. (But now instead you quoted numbers too which weren't quoted in your Postman screenshot.) It's best to copy the existing request body that works in Postman and just duplicate the quotes in it... (And as mentioned, Fiddler could help to understand what is actually sent and received.)

Comment: Thanks @CherryDT, your guidance of inserting the "Quotes" is correct. However, I think something wrong with my existing request body, i had made some changes and manage to get the response from the API, updated the fixed code above. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by CherryDT - Your original `reqBody` had alot of missing quotes and in your updated `reqBody`, you are missing quotes for `order_date` and also you quoted `pageSize` and `pageNum` value which is supposed to be a number and thus quotes is not required:

Below should give you the same JSON string as what you had in Postman:

```
reqBody = "{""methodType"":""extract"",""sourceApplication"":""DSA"",""searchParameter"":[{""conditionType"":""term"",""key"":""global_bu_id"",""value"":""11""},{""conditionType"":""wildcard"",""key"":""customer_num"",""value"":[""530007546697""]},{""conditionType"":""range"",""key"":""order_date"",""value"":[{""from"":""2021-08-31"",""to"":""2021-09-09""}]},{""conditionType"":""sort"",""key"":""order_date_time"",""value"":""desc""}],""pageSize"":40,""pageNum"":0}"
```

One way which has been working well for me so far is:

1. Copy the JSON string from Postman to Notepad
2. Open Replace dialog (Ctrl-H)
3. Enter `"` in Find What
4. Enter `""` in Replace with
5. Click **Replace All**

Now you can copied the new string back to your VBA editor and it should produce the same output as Postman's.

Comment: Thanks Raymond, "Quotes" is one of the issues in the beginning. However, the structure of the request body is wrong as well. I had made some changes and manage to get the response from the API, updated the fixed code above. Thank you