# Post request to Microsoft graph API

Tags: excel, vba, rest, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to request an access token with vba code. When putting all the parameters I give in VBA into postman I get an access token no problem but when using it in VBA code it gives the error

> "the request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'"

```
    Dim objRequestGetToken As Object, JSONGetToken As Object
    Dim strUrlGetToken As String, strClientID As String, strClientSecret As String, strResource As String, strBody As String
    Dim blnAsyncGetToken As Boolean

    strClientID = "XXX"
    strClientSecret = "XXX"
    strRecourse = "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/XXX.sharepoint.com@XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    
    strBody = "{""grant_type"":""client_credentials"",""client_id"":""" & strClientID & """,""client_secret"":""" & strClientSecret & """,""resource"":""" & strRecourse & """}"

    Set objRequestGetToken = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    strUrlGetToken = "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/tokens/OAuth/2/"
    blnAsyncGetToken = False
    Debug.Print strBody

    With objRequestGetToken
        .Open "POST", strUrlGetToken, blnAsyncGetToken
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose"
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose"
        .send strBody
        'spin wheels whilst waiting for response
        While objRequestGetToken.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        Set JSONGetData = JsonConverter.ParseJson(objRequestGetToken.ResponseText)
    End With

    Debug.Print objRequestGetToken.ResponseText
```

I know this is a possible duplicate request with [VBA post method request body ("MSXML2.XMLHTTP"): Error Parsing JSON: ^ Expecting '{' or '['](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69150097/vba-post-method-request-body-msxml2-xmlhttp-error-parsing-json-expecting) but I can't figure out why my body is not properly being sent and the post previously mentioned doesn't seem to help.

postman request:
[image]
[image]

Any kind of help would be much appreciated!

Edit: Here's the code that made it work eventually :)

```
    Dim objRequestGetToken As Object, JSONGetToken As Object
    Dim strUrlGetToken As String, strClientID As String, strClientSecret As String, strResource As String, strBody As String
    Dim blnAsyncGetToken As Boolean

    strClientID = "XXX"
    strClientSecret = "XXX"
    strRecourse = "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/XXX.sharepoint.com@XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    
    strBody = "{""grant_type"":""client_credentials"",""client_id"":""" & strClientID & """,""client_secret"":""" & strClientSecret & """,""resource"":""" & strRecourse & """}"

    Set objRequestGetToken = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    strUrlGetToken = "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/tokens/OAuth/2/"
    blnAsyncGetToken = False
    Debug.Print strBody

    With objRequestGetToken
        .Open "POST", strUrlGetToken, blnAsyncGetToken
        .SetRequestHeader "application", "x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose"
        .send strBody
        'spin wheels whilst waiting for response
        While objRequestGetToken.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        Set JSONGetData = JsonConverter.ParseJson(objRequestGetToken.ResponseText)
    End With

    Debug.Print objRequestGetToken.ResponseText
```

Comment: Note that `Dim strUrlGetToken, strClientID, strClientSecret, strResource, strBody As String` defines only `strBody As String` and all others as `Variant` but `Dim strUrlGetToken As String, strClientID As String, strClientSecret As String, strResource As String, strBody As String` defines all of them as `String`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable or it is `Variant` by default.

Comment: I haven't worked with the Graph API myself yet, but looking at this [PS sample](http://laurierhodes.info/?q=node/137), it seems you need to specify a value vor `grant_type`.

Comment: So when you `Debug.Print strBody` and copy-paste the output from the immediate window to Postman, the request work? Is there any documentation for this particular API?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks I didn't know that. I've edited the code.

Comment: @HelO'Ween Hi thanks for the reply, you are correct I have to specify a value for the key "grant_type". But I think I have done so. in my strBody string I have all parameters I need included and the values they need. Unless my syntax is wrong but I've tried many different things.

Comment: @RaymondWu not exactly.. I did the opposite. All the values that are in VBA are the ones I copy pasted from postman with the exception of the body in which I had to do double quotes because of how VBA code is written.

Comment: @TeunSmeyers Are you sure the API expects a JSON and not something else?

Comment: @TeumSmeyers In that case I suggest you try what I said and see if the request works. If it does then look at the other headers sent by Postman and see what's different.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ all requests I can find for the Graph API seem to be in json formatting so I assume it is? The documentation also gives an example in JSON

Comment: Is `odata=verbose` necessary in `Content-Type` header? I admit I don't use Graph API but usually I only see `application/json`. If the documentation is public, can you share it? Or copy-paste the details in your question

Comment: Try to `setRequestHeader "application", "x-www-form-urlencoded"` instead and `.send "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" & strClientID & "&client_secret=" & strClientSecret & "&resource=" & strRecourse`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ still the same error.

Comment: @RaymondWu here's a link to the graph api documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0

Also I tried to put the ```Debug.Print strBody``` in postman and it also said "grant_type" is not in the request

Comment: I swear i saw you said that copy-pasting the output from immediate window to Postman worked just now.... can you take a screenshot of your Postman setting that was working? The endpoint, header and body. Perhaps just the string of the body that was working. Be sure to redact the sensitive info @TeunSmeyers

Comment: @RaymondWu correct I did comment that but deleted it because when I tried again it no longer worked. I think I sent the wrong request.

Regardless I added the pictures of how it works in postman to my original post

Comment: @TeunSmeyers did you kick out the `.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose"` when you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Well that's weird because the body is a form-data. Can you tried what PeH said just now (`.Send "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" & strClientID & "&client_secret=" & strClientSecret & "&resource=" & strRecourse`) but keep the content type header as `application/json;odata=verborse`?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ you are correct I forgot to remove the "Content-Type" paramater! IT WORKS NOW! 

Thank you both so much!!

Comment: @RaymondWu turns out leaving the json;odata-verbose was what was wrong because changing it to "x-www-form-urlencoded" made it all work!

Comment: @TeumSmeyers Was about to say that, the body in postman is not json in any way (its located under  `Raw`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strBody = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" & strClientID & "&client_secret=" & strClientSecret & "&resource=" & strRecourse
```

and changing the header to `x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
With objRequestGetToken
    .Open "POST", strUrlGetToken, blnAsyncGetToken
    .SetRequestHeader "application", "x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose"
    .send strBody
    'spin wheels whilst waiting for response
    While objRequestGetToken.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Set JSONGetData = JsonConverter.ParseJson(objRequestGetToken.ResponseText)
End With
```

should solve the issue.